# C++ refactoring arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi I'm new at C++ and I want to create an array like this but in C++:

```
    rooms {

        1 { 'name' : 'Room1' },
        2 { 'name' : 'Room2' }

    }
```

Can someone help me with this? Tanks for your time

Comment: You are asking for a dictionary (map), not lists.

Comment: Like `std::vector<int, std::pair<std::string, std::string> >` ?

Comment: Have a look at the array of structs example at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/ , although you might want to store them in a better container than an array: a set, list, or vector, or an indexed type as map, would be more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Define a `struct` or `class` to represent the room data and use a `std::vector` , `std::map` or `std::unorderd_map` to store the rooms:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

struct Room {
   std::string name;
   Room(std::string _name) : name(_name) {}
   Room() {}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Room> rooms{{"Room1"}, {"Room2"}};
    std::cout << rooms[0].name << std::endl; // prints "Room1"

    std::map<int, Room> roomsMap{
        {1, Room{"Room1"}},
        {2, Room{"Room2"}}
    };
    std::cout << roomsMap[1].name << std::endl; // prints "Room1"
    return 0;
}
```